# Read JTextfield put into word file

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

I create a small GUI with Netbeans. I've got an issue with settext and gettext. I'm raelly happy if you can say whre the problem is and what i have to do or you show me the solution.

i want to create a word file by clicking a button. This is working fine but there should be some text out of a JTextfiel in the word file and this isnt working.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import java.io.IOException;



 private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   try{

       FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("Bewerberinterview.docx");
       XWPFDocument doc;
       doc = new XWPFDocument();
       XWPFParagraph paraTit=doc.createParagraph();
       paraTit.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
       XWPFRun paraTitRun=paraTit.createRun();
       paraTitRun.setBold(true);
       paraTitRun.setFontSize(20);
       paraTitRun.setText(title.getText());
       doc.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak();
       doc.createParagraph().createRun().setText(name_content.getText());
       doc.write(outStream);
       doc.close();
      System.out.println("createdocument.docx written successully");
   }catch (HeadlessException | IOException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
}
```

When I starting my application and put in some Text in the box and clicking "button 1 = create". The file will create fine but there is no text in it.

Comment: What do you get? What do you want/expect to get? Note that operating system and exact versions of software in use (up to date?) might be relevant.

Comment: Do `outStream.close();` after `doc.write(outStream);`. If that not helps do debugging. What returns `title.getText()`? What returns `name_content.getText()` in context of that code?

Comment: Thank for your replies. Its netbeans 11.1. and apache-poi-bin 4.1.0. I do outStream.close();

Comment: I do                     outStream.close();      after       doc.write(outStream)     . it isnt any change.      tiitle.gettext()      and      name_content.gettext()       are JTextFields which you can Type in Various text.

Comment: "I do outStream.close(); after doc.write(outStream)": Really? Your code doesn't show that. "tiitle.gettext() and name_content.gettext() are JTextFields which you can Type in Various text":  Yes, but what does `title.getText()` and `name_content.getText()` return in context of your code? Maybe both return empty strings? Do some debugging, as I said.

Comment: i'm begging to work with java sorry im really sorry i dont no what mean. Probably you mean I need a separated String to use get text?

Answer (score 0):

The following code, which is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your described problem, works as I would expect it should.

For each click on button `write` it writes the file `Bewerberinterview.docx` file having content from the both text fields.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField title;
    protected JTextField name_content;
    protected JButton write;

    public TextDemo() {
        super();

        title = new JTextField(20);
        name_content = new JTextField(20);
        write = new JButton("write");
        write.addActionListener(this);

        add(title);
        add(name_content);
        add(write);

   }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String titleText = title.getText();
        String name_contentText = name_content.getText();
        System.out.println(titleText);
        System.out.println(name_contentText);

        try {
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("Bewerberinterview.docx");
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setBold(true);
            run.setFontSize(20);
            run.setText(titleText);
            doc.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak();
            doc.createParagraph().createRun().setText(name_contentText);
            doc.write(outStream);
            outStream.close();
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("File " + new File("Bewerberinterview.docx").getAbsolutePath() + " written successully.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new TextDemo());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So your described problem does not exists.

It does? Well then show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the problem.

Comment: thank you for you code. i runned the file and it have this failures:       "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException

Comment: You need all the `apache poi` jars in your class path. For needed jars see [Component Map](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components). The missed `org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException` is in `xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar`.

Comment: Thank You that works perfectly! You solved my problem. And other problem i have is: how can i open a youtube in JPanel? Should I open a new Thread or you know the answer?

Comment: @Marius Schöttli: Please ask a new question about this new problem. But do some own effort first. I have never done this, but internet search with keywords `jpanel embed browser` shows promising results.